# Pressing android app button for a second time causes crash

Tags: java, android, xml, android-camera

I made an application with a simple SOS button, when I press the button it sends an SOS signal in morse code from the flashlight. This works fine. But when I press the button a second time, or run the app a second time it just crashes.

After that it works again for 1 time.

I don't have a clue on what is going wrong.

Here is my code from the main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public final static String SOS_MORSE = "111000111";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendSOS(View view) {
    /* Open the camera and get the parameters to control the flashlight */
    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    char prevChar = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < SOS_MORSE.length(); i++) {
        /* If it's part of the S's the signal has to be faster, short on, short off */
        if (SOS_MORSE.charAt(i) == '1') {
            /* The last char was a 0 so it was part of the letter O signal, so we pause for a brief time to distinguish between the signals of the O and the S */
            if(prevChar == '0'){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50); /* Pause for a very short time */
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            /* Turn the camera on */
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();

            /* Short on */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(120);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* Turn the camera off */
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            cam.setParameters(p);

            /* Short off */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(120);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prevChar = SOS_MORSE.charAt(i);
        } else { /* If it's part of the O, the signals have to be longer */
            /* The last char was a 1 so it was part of the letter S signal, so we pause for a brief time to distinguish between the signals of the S and the O */
            if(prevChar == '1'){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50); /* Pause for a very short time */
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            /* Turn the camera on */
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();

            /* Turn it on for a longer time */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* Turn the camera off */
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            cam.setParameters(p);

            /* Turn it off for a longer time */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prevChar = SOS_MORSE.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    cam = null;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the activity main xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFlashlight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="sendSOS" 
    android:text="SOS" />
```

And this is the manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In logcat it says it failed to connect to camera service , this line of code :

`Camera cam = Camera.open();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must follow Android Guidelines in using the `Camera`

Instead of

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
```

Use

```
Camera cam = getCameraInstance();
// check for null, if it is, then camera is either not available or in use
...
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

And also after using the `Camera`(if your already done with it),  Use the `release()` method of Camera` and Use a try catch block with finally

```
  /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
  public void sendSOS(View view) {
      Camera cam = null;
      try{
         cam = getCameraInstance();
         ...
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         // TODO: if camera is null 
         // find a work around
         // either prompt user that camera is still not available
         // or(bad idea) recursion with ProgressBar
         // like sendSOS(view); and let the user wait using Handler
         // if these doesnt work, add a callback to the camera
         // `Camera.ErrorCallback`
         // if CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED will return in `onError(int,Camera)`
         // then In this case, the application must release the Camera object and instantiate a new one.
      }
      finally{
         // this should be in a worker thread, and use a callback if camera is already release
         // in some cases this should work, but in order not to block the main thread
         // we can use asynctask to release the camera resources here and use a callback
         // whenever the onPostExecute executes, then trigger a function that camera is ready again to              
         // be opened
         cam.release(); 
      }
  }
```

Right below is from Android Guide, that you must check for exceptions, And i think Camera is already available that is why you got an exception in your logcat.

**Caution**: Always check for exceptions when using Camera.open(). Failing to check for exceptions if the camera is in use or does not exist will cause your application to be shut down by the system.

Further reading the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Hope that will help :)

Comment: Thanks, that made it work for me. But I'm doubting if this will not give an error if the getInstance returns null, in finally you still do cam.release(), if cam is null you get a null pointerexception. I'm wondering if my solution would have worked with only a cam.release at the end?

Comment: @user3801533 view my edit, put a catch exception in your try catch finally block.